# Access an Angular 2 component's injector from within the component

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

For learning purposes I'd like to access an Angular 2 component's injector from within the component to examine.

Comment: Just inject it into your constructor : `constructor(injector: Injector) {console.log(injector);}`. Don't forget to import it from `angular2/angular2`